# Django is having trouble finding static folder/css

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Django project in which I am getting a 404 on the CSS file. In my app (the only one I have) I have a template directory with a few different HTML files. I also have a static directory (found in the same directory as app) I have a CSS file saved as such /static/css/main.css/.

See below for my **settings.py** file which sets the static folder:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5&-12%c=er64$=$0w6*0sc__s8k_4ldiq(mkowlmqdatn!!g!8'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'feed'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kahlo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kahlo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
```

My **main.html** file links to my desired CSS file as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">
```

With the load static tag at the top of the file:

```
{% load static %}
```

However, the CSS file is never loaded and I receive a 404. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the wrong path when referencing your css file. Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

You will note I removed the leading / from the path. The leading slash makes the path absolute, where as you may require a relative path within the Django project depending on how it is structured.

Also, make sure you have the file in a folder in the root of the project:

```
project_root
  -- app1
  -- app2
  -- static
     -- css
       -- main.css
```

All the best